# Inserting values in MySQL using an array

Tags: java

I have a very large input form with over 90 fields and i need to store all the values in a database.

The following is just a test sample code to show how i am inserting my values right now.

```js
public void insertToDB() {
  Connection con = SoftwareConnectionFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
  PreparedStatement ps = null;

  String sql = "INSERT INTO person.test (name, class, subject) "
    + "VALUES(?,?,?)";
  try {
   ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   ps.setString(1, name);
   ps.setString(2, class);
   ps.setString(3, subject);
   
    ps.executeUpdate();
   
  } catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("error storing into db: " + e.getMessage());
  } finally {
   SoftwareConnectionFactory.getInstance().closeConnection(con);
  }  
 }
```

The above code works just fine but i am trying to find a neat way of coding this by setting it with help of an array. I looked into the following:

```
String[] check = { name, class, subject };
Array arrayCcheck = con.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", check);
```

The `createArrayOf` is not supported by my current dbpc and i am trying to find alternate ways of doing this. I have tried updating my jar files but the above method still doesn't work. I am trying to keep my code as short as possible. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following:

Reduce number of fields in your table to only those fields that you are currently using for search queries (you can also think of something that might be used in the future). As a result you will not have 90 fields table.

To store everything else, you can parse your object to JSON and store entire object in one additional table field. When you will read from database you will parse it back.

So as a result you will have something like that:

WRITE

```
ObjectWith90Fields obj;
String sql = "INSERT INTO person.test (name, class, json) "
                + "VALUES(?,?,?)";
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, obj.getName());
            ps.setString(2, obj.getClass());
            ps.setString(3, createJson(obj));

             ps.executeUpdate();

        }
```

READ

```
ObjectWith90Fields obj;
String sql = "SELECT * FROM person.test";
        try {
            st = con.createStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = st.execute(sql);
            ObjectWith90Fields obj = parseJson(rs.getString("json"));           

        }
```